# Referencing specific child nodes mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to export a list of all the Reference child nodes with the attribute input. There are about 1000 documents in the collection. The desired output would be a find() query that only outputs the contents of the Reference field within the Tag field.

For example:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5dfb7189986b7c30f33987c3"),
        "Tag" : [
                {
                        "attribute" : "input",
                        "Reference" : "product"
                },
                {
                        "attribute" : "more",
                        "Reference" : "extra"
                }
        ]
}
```

Output:
`[product]`

My query at the moment:

```
db.test.find(
    {$and :
    [
        { "Tag.attribute":"input"},
        {"Tag.attribute": { $ne:null}}
    ]}
    ,{_id:0,"Tag.Reference":"1"}).pretty()
```

Returns:
`[product,extra]`

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: what would be the expected output?

Comment: [product] @AnuragWagh

Comment: does it have to be the first element from Tag? or where Tag.attribute == "input"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to extract the first Reference from the `Tag` attribute.

You can use the aggregation pipeline to achieve this.

**Prepare Data:**

```
db.collection.insertMany([{
        "Tag" : [
                {
                        "attribute" : "input",
                        "Reference" : "product2"
                },
                {
                        "attribute" : "more",
                        "Reference" : "extra"
                }
        ]
},
{
        "Tag" : [
                {
                        "attribute" : "input",
                        "Reference" : "product1"
                },
                {
                        "attribute" : "more",
                        "Reference" : "extra"
                }
        ]
}])
```

**Aggergation Framework:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group :{
            _id:null,
            reference :{$push : {$arrayElemAt: ["$Tag.Reference", 0]}}
        }
    }
    ])
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "reference" : [
        "product2",
        "product1"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want may be a filter as part of an aggregation.

This question gives some interesting solutions:
[Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Based on that I learnt that a filter can pull out the relevant items in the array.

The steps for your problem could be:

1. your match statement
2. a projection with a filter to get just the right array elements
3. another projection or grouping to get only the data you want

So this should get you the data in MongoDB 3.2+.

```
db.test.aggregate([
   {$match: { "Tag.attribute":"input"}},
   {$project: {"Tag": 
        {$filter: {input: '$Tag', as: 'item',cond: {$eq: ['$$item.attribute', 'input']}}}}},
    {$project:{"Tag.Reference":1,_id:0}}])
```

Output

```
{ "Tag" : [ { "Reference" : "product" } ] }
```

Note: with the dummy data provided the initial match is not needed.

To see the filter step in isolation try this:

```
db.test.aggregate([       
    {$project: 
    {"Tag":          
        {$filter: {input: '$Tag', as: 'item',cond: {$eq: ['$$item.attribute', 'input']}}}
}}])
```